# Why use === when you are sure types are equal?

Tags: javascript, types, equality, jslint

It seems that the strict equality operator is preferred whenever possible - I put my code in JSLint and got the following feedback.

Code:

```
function log() {
    console.log(arguments.length == 1 ? arguments[0] : arguments);
}
```

Feedback from JSLint:

```
Problem at line 2 character 34: Expected '===' and instead saw '=='.
```

I am curious to know what advantages `===` has over `==` here. Basically, `.length` returns a `Number`, and `1` is a `Number` as well. You can be 100% sure, so `===` is just a redundant extra token. Also, checking for the type whilst you know the types will always be the same has no performance advantage either.

So what's actually the reason behind using `===` here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only reason is that you don't have to think whether the comparison you are doing will involve coercion or not. If you stick to using `===`, you just have one thing less to worry about.

Of course [not everyone agrees](http://webreflection.blogspot.com/2010/10/javascript-coercion-demystified.html). This is why you can [disable specific checks](http://www.jslint.com/#JSLINT_OPTIONS) in JSlint, if you are sure of what you are doing.

Comment: I might be stupid, but could you please tell me where the options page has an option for `===`/`==`?

Comment: Er... it  used to have it. It was called `eqeqeq`, but now I cannot find it anyumore.

Comment: It used to be in JSlint as well.

Comment: Eqeqeq got removed in the recent JSLint rewrite.  If you really want it you can grab an older version of jslint from GitHub.

Answer (score 1):

It's not strictly required, as you know the `length` function is well-tested. But what if `length` was a bit buggy, and there was a chance it could return `false`?

In this situation, both `0` and `false` would be evaluated as false using the `==` comparison. To test for false (when there is also the chance of `0` being returned), you need to also check the data type, which is where `===` comes in.

Answer (score 1):

Well, `===` is supposed to be infinitesimally faster, as it can fail faster (on type mismatch), but that's deep inside the "pointless microoptimizations" territory.

Realistically, I'd advise for `===`, even if you are 105% sure - I've been tripped up by my assumptions too many times ("yes, I am positive they are the ... same ... uh ..."). Unless there's a good reason to turn them off, it is better to keep sanity checks enabled in code than trust to do them in your mind.